# Add source files to cocoa project not intended for compile

Tags: cocoa, compiler-construction

I'm writing a cocoa application which should copy files to a given directory. The files should be part of the app, **but not compiled**. I'm thinking of a folder, e.g. "MySources", where I want to add all .a, .m and .xip files, which should not be compiled. These files should be left as they are - so plain and editable text. Then my app provides a button and when a user clicks on that button, the app copies all files within the "MySources" folder to a given directory.

Comment: Try not including these files into Build Phases

Comment: I don't have them included into Build Phases. But how can I add them to my compiled .app? They need to be some part of the compiled .app file.

Comment: Not sure If I understand you : you want those files to be included (aka copied) in your Application bundle so that you can later copy them on your client's computer , right ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a Copy Files build phase, configure it to copy to the desired destination within the app bundle, and add the desired files to that build phase.

Answer (score 0):

In `Target > Build Phases` remove the appropriate files in `Compile Resources` and add `Copy Files` build phases to copy the files to the destination locations in the bundle.